# Getting error when Azure Function deployed, but not when run locally

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I've created an Azure Function (C#, Visual Studio).

This runs fine on my local PC, but when deployed to the Azure 'cloud' and run, it returns with this error for the same message:

```
Exception while executing function: myListener Exception binding parameter 'deliveryCount'
Binding data does not contain expected value 'deliveryCount'.
```

Searching for this error doesn't return anything helpful. Any ideas where to start looking?

Thanks

Here's the relevant code:

```
[FunctionName("myListener")]
[Singleton("ItemsLock", SingletonScope.Host)]
public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("myQueue","mySubscription",Connection = "myServiceBusConnectionString"]
    Message message,
    int deliveryCount, // seems to be the culprit
    MessageReceiver messageReceiver,
    string lockToken,
    ILogger log,
    ExecutionContext context)
{...}
```

Comment: Show us how you are invoking it locally.

Comment: I simply run the VS project in Debug. It connects to the Message Subscription using local.settings file.

Comment: @radders have you deployed the `appsettings.json` to the function settings?

Comment: Yes, settings deployed to Azure

Comment: Seems like your code need a ')'. Can you edit about it? `public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("myQueue","mySubscription",Connection = "myServiceBusConnectionString"]
    Message message,
    int deliveryCount, // seems to be the culprit
    MessageReceiver messageReceiver,
    string lockToken,
    ILogger log,
    ExecutionContext context)` Here need a `)`.

Comment: Yes, a ')' is missing after the connection string in the pasted code above. It IS there in the real code, so not the problem.